# Default values for environment variables in .npmrc

Tags: bash, shell, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

Does somebody know how to set default environment variables in .npmrc files ? I tried to do this:

```
registry=${myEnvVariable:-https://myregistry.com}
```

and this:

```
defaultRegistry=https://myregistry.com
registry=${myEnvVariable:-defaultRegistry}
```

These solutions don't work because I got "Failed to replace env in config"

Comment: The short answer is _"No"_ because [.npmrc](https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/npmrc.html) files are [INI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) formatted, and AFAIK they (INI) cannot contain conditional logic.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not supported. One way of doing what you want is to write a wrapper script around npm:

`~/bin/npm`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
defaultRegistry=https://myregistry.com
myRegistry=${myEnvVariable:-$defaultRegistry}
export myRegistry
exec /usr/bin/npm "$@"
```

`~/.npmrc`:

```ini
registry=${myRegistry}
```

Then of course, prepend `$HOME/bin` to `PATH` in your ~/.bash_profile. Ubuntu does this automatically in the `.profile` it adds for new users.

```bash
[[ :$PATH: = *:$HOME/bin:* ]] || echo 'PATH=~/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Test opening up a new shell and typing `type -p npm` to make sure it's finding the one in `~/bin/npm`.

### `.npmrc` support for environment variables

The [`npmrc` man page](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/npmrc#files) does not mention support for the shell-specific conditional logic, so unfortunately it doesn't seem like it's supported (not yet anyway as of v10):

> All npm config files are an ini-formatted list of `key = value` parameters.
> Environment variables can be replaced using `${VARIABLE_NAME}`. For
> example:
>
> ```
> prefix = ${HOME}/.npm-packages
> ```